# NSDateFormatter return null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to format a NSDate to a string with date format of yyyyMMdd, here's the code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *date =data.createdTime;

NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

the NSLog return me this value

```
Tue, 24 May 2011 0:05:01 +0800
(null)
```

Anyone know which part is wrong?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps `currentArticle.createdTime` is a valid date but `data.createdTime` is `nil`? In addition, you are performing the `-setDateFormat:` selector on `dateFormat`, but it seems like your date formatter is `dateFormatter`.

Try the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *date = data.createdTime;

NSLog(@"   Normal Date = %@", date);
NSLog(@"Formatted Date = %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date]);

[dateFormatter release];
```

If `date` is `nil`, then both `NSLog()` calls will tell you.

---

## Edit

Double check that `data.createdTime` is an `NSDate` instance. Perhaps it is an instance of another class, such as `NSString`, whose `-description` returns the displayed date. This would explain why `NSLog()` “shows” the date, but the formatter is returning nil.

```
BOOL isDate = [data.createdTime isKindOfClass: [NSDate class]];
NSLog(@"Date %@ a date.", isDate ? @"is" : @"is not");
```

Comment: Hi, 
the result still the same as what I stated, the date have the complete value, and the formatted is still null.

Comment: U mean the one that u post in this post right? If yes, then yep, I followed ur code n it still return me null for the formatted date.

Comment: tq man.. It turn out, the date is in string format.. All I need to do just change it to date format, and format it, voila the code works. Thanx again..

Comment: VOILA! The answer is in the details!

Answer (score 0):

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
```

Should be:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
```

If it still isn't working then something is wrong with `data.createdTime;` because I ran this code and recieved the expected output:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```

Comment: I think something wrong with the value extracted from the data.createdTime, since if I set the value of date to NSDate date, it'll work just fine. But when I NSLog the data.createdTime, it show me the correct value of date, but only when I format it, it become null.